# @ManagedProperty - access properties Injected from one view scoped bean into another view scoped bean

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection

I have injected one view scoped bean into another view scoped bean , and I can access some properties of the first bean but others appear as null in @PostContruct. How can I see their real value?

Thanks in advance

Update:
I can only see the value of properties updated in @PostContruct of the first bean and not others

Bean 1(SelectOfferMpans)

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package sofyc.backingbean.offer;

import es.iberdrola.configuration.LogginManager;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import sofyc.bean.BeanInstanceLocator;
import sofyc.bean.IOffersBean;
import sofyc.corejsf.SofycNavigation;
import sofyc.corejsf.SofycParamNames;
import sofyc.utils.JSFHelper;
import sofyc.valueobject.CustomerFindVO;
import sofyc.valueobject.MpanVO;
import sofyc.valueobject.OfferSitesVO;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SelectOfferMpans implements Serializable{

/**
 * Logger.
 */
private static Logger log = LogginManager.getLogger(SelectOfferMpans.class.getName());

static {          
    adq_ren_types = new String[2];
}

private final String ID_OFFER_SELECT_MPANS_FORM = "selectMpans"; 

private String menuOrigin;

/**
 * Parametro de busqueda del formulario.
 */
private String registrationNumber;

private List<CustomerFindVO> customerfoundList;

private CustomerFindVO customerfound;

private String companyRegNo;

private String customerId;

private CustomerFindVO selectedCustomer;

private List<OfferSitesVO> offerSites;

private List<OfferSitesVO> filteredSites;

private OfferSitesVO selectedSite; 

private OfferSitesVO[] selectedSites;

private List<MpanVO> siteMpans;

private SelectItem[] hh_nhh_List;  

private SelectItem[] adq_ren_List;

private final static String[] adq_ren_types;

private Map<String,String> hh_nhh_types;

public Map<String, String> getHh_nhh_types() {
    return hh_nhh_types;
}

public void setHh_nhh_types(Map<String, String> hh_nhh_types) {
    this.hh_nhh_types = hh_nhh_types;
}

public SelectItem[] getHh_nhh_List() {
    return hh_nhh_List;
}

public void setHh_nhh_List(SelectItem[] hh_nhh_List) {
    this.hh_nhh_List = hh_nhh_List;
}

public SelectItem[] getAdq_ren_List() {
    return adq_ren_List;
}

public void setAdq_ren_List(SelectItem[] adq_ren_List) {
    this.adq_ren_List = adq_ren_List;
}    

public List<OfferSitesVO> getOfferSites() {
    return offerSites;        
}

public void setOfferSites(List<OfferSitesVO> offerSites) {
    this.offerSites = offerSites;
}

public List<OfferSitesVO> getFilteredSites() {
    return filteredSites;
}

public void setFilteredSites(List<OfferSitesVO> filteredSites) {
    this.filteredSites = filteredSites;
}

public OfferSitesVO getSelectedSite() {
    return selectedSite;
}

public void setSelectedSite(OfferSitesVO selectedSite) {
    this.selectedSite = selectedSite;
}

public OfferSitesVO[] getSelectedSites() {
    return selectedSites;
}

public void setSelectedSites(OfferSitesVO[] selectedSites) {
    this.selectedSites = selectedSites;
}

public List<MpanVO> getSiteMpans() {
    return siteMpans;
}

public void setSiteMpans(List<MpanVO> siteMpans) {
    this.siteMpans = siteMpans;
}

public CustomerFindVO getSelectedCustomer() {
    return selectedCustomer;
}

public void setSelectedCustomer(CustomerFindVO selectedCustomer) {
    this.selectedCustomer = selectedCustomer;
}

public String getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

public String getCompanyRegNo() {
    return companyRegNo;
}

public void setCompanyRegNo(String companyRegNo) {
    this.companyRegNo = companyRegNo;
}

public List<CustomerFindVO> getCustomerfoundList() {
    return customerfoundList;
}

public void setCustomerfoundList(List<CustomerFindVO> customerfoundList) {
    this.customerfoundList = customerfoundList;
}

public String getRegistrationNumber() {
    return registrationNumber;
}

public void setRegistrationNumber(String registrationNumber) {
    this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
}

public CustomerFindVO getCustomerfound() {
    return customerfound;
}

public void setCustomerfound(CustomerFindVO customerfound) {
    this.customerfound = customerfound;
}

public String getMenuOrigin() {
    return menuOrigin;
}

public void setMenuOrigin(String menuOrigin) {
    this.menuOrigin = menuOrigin;
}

/**
 * Creates a new instance of SelectOfferMpans
 */
public SelectOfferMpans() {
}

@PostConstruct    
public void init() {
    try{
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("INIT");
        } 

        if (getMenuOrigin() == null) {
            setMenuOrigin(JSFHelper.getParameterFromView("OPTION"));     
            if (getMenuOrigin() == null) {
                setMenuOrigin((String) JSFHelper.getParameterFromRequest("OPTION"));
            }
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("CREATE OFFER --> guardado en VIEW VAR menuOrigin el "
                        + "valor recuperado en la Request del parametro OPTION:: " 
                        + getMenuOrigin());
            }
        }

        adq_ren_types[0] = "Adquisitions";
        adq_ren_types[1] = "Renews";

        this.setHh_nhh_types(cargaHHNHH());

        //hh_nhh_List = createFilterOptions(hh_nhh_types);
        hh_nhh_List = createFilterOptions1(hh_nhh_types,true);
        adq_ren_List = createFilterOptions(adq_ren_types);   

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.error("SearchCustomer:Init", e);
        JSFHelper.addErrorMessage("messagesError", e.getMessage());            
    }
}

public void findCustomer() throws Exception {    
    CustomerFindVO customer=null;
    try{        
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Searching Customer....");
        }

        IOffersBean offersBean = BeanInstanceLocator.getOffersBean();
        customerfound = offersBean.searchCustomer(companyRegNo);
        if (customerfound!=null){
            this.setOfferSites(offersBean.getCustomerSites(customerfound.getCustomerId()));                
        }
        else{
            this.setOfferSites(null);
            JSFHelper.addErrorMessage(ID_OFFER_SELECT_MPANS_FORM, "Error searching customer");
        }

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Customer Data Found");
        }

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        log.error("findCustomer:", t);
        JSFHelper.addErrorMessage(ID_OFFER_SELECT_MPANS_FORM, "Error searching customer");                        
    }
}

public String goToOffers(){
    try{

        JSFHelper.addParamToRequest(SofycParamNames.CUSTOMER_ID, customerfound.getCustomerId());
        JSFHelper.addParamToRequest(SofycParamNames.OPTION, this.getMenuOrigin());
        return SofycNavigation.VIEW_CREATE_OFFERS_PAGE;

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        log.error("goToOffers:", t);
        JSFHelper.addErrorMessage(ID_OFFER_SELECT_MPANS_FORM, "Error navigating to offers page");            
        return null;
    }
}        

private SelectItem[] createFilterOptions(String[] data)  {  
    SelectItem[] options = new SelectItem[data.length + 1];  

    options[0] = new SelectItem("", "Select");         
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
        options[i + 1] = new SelectItem(data[i], data[i]);  
    }  

    return options;  
}

private SelectItem[] createFilterOptions1(Map<String,String> data, boolean select)  {  
    //SelectItem[] options = new SelectItem[data.size() + 1];  
    SelectItem[] options;
    int i = 0;

    if (select==true) {
        options = new SelectItem[data.size() + 1];
        options[i] = new SelectItem("", "Select");  
        i++;
    }
    else{
        options = new SelectItem[data.size()];
    }
    for (Map.Entry e: data.entrySet()) { 
        options[i] = new SelectItem(e.getKey().toString(), e.getValue().toString());  
        //options[i + 1] = new SelectItem(e.getValue().toString(),e.getKey().toString());  
        i++;
    } 

    return options;  
}

private Map<String,String> cargaHHNHH() {
     Map<String,String> hh_nhh_types= new HashMap<String,String>();

    hh_nhh_types.put("HH","HH");
    hh_nhh_types.put("NHH","NHH");
    return hh_nhh_types;
}
```

}

Bean 2(CreateOffer)   property selectedSites of the first bean appears always as null and It's loaded in findCustomer Method.

```
package sofyc.backingbean.offer;

import es.iberdrola.configuration.LogginManager;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.ToggleEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.UnselectEvent;
import sofyc.bean.BeanInstanceLocator;
import sofyc.bean.IOffersBean;
import sofyc.utils.JSFHelper;
import sofyc.valueobject.CustomerVO;
import sofyc.valueobject.MddMeasurementClassVO;
import sofyc.valueobject.MpanVO;
import sofyc.valueobject.OfferSitesVO;
import sofyc.valueobject.ProfileClassVO;
import sofyc.valueobject.SiteVO;
import sofyc.valueobject.TradebookVO;


@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CreateOffer implements Serializable {

private static Logger log = LogginManager.getLogger(CreateOffer.class.getName());    
/**
 * Creates a new instance of CreateOffer
 */
static {          
    adq_ren_types = new String[2];
}  

@ManagedProperty(value="#{selectOfferMpans.selectedSites}")
//@ManagedProperty(value="#{selectOfferMpans}")
//private SelectOfferMpans selectOfferMpans;
private OfferSitesVO[] selectedSites;

/*public void setSelectOfferMpans(SelectOfferMpans selectOfferMpans) {
    this.selectOfferMpans = selectOfferMpans;
}*/

public void setSelectedSites(OfferSitesVO[] selectedSites) {
    this.selectedSites = selectedSites;
}

/**
 * Valores posibles de donde viene la pagina.
 */    
private final String CREATE_OFFERS_OPTION = "CREATE";
private final String OFFERS_OPTION = "OFFERS";

private String menuOrigin;

/**
 * Corresponde a la columna CUSTOMER_ID.
 */
private Integer customerId;

private Map<String,String> managers;
private Date offerFromDate;
private Date offerToDate;
private Date expiryDate;

private Integer tradeBookId;

private String creditScore;

private String consultantMargin;
private String spMargin;

private Integer productId;
private Integer profileClassId;        
private String measurementClassId;    
private Integer curveId;    

/**
 * Customer selected.
 */
private CustomerVO customer;    
private List<OfferSitesVO> offerSites;
private List<OfferSitesVO> filteredSites;
private OfferSitesVO selectedSite;      
private OfferSitesVO[] selectedSites1;

public OfferSitesVO[] getSelectedSites1() {
    return selectedSites1;
}

public void setSelectedSites1(OfferSitesVO[] selectedSites1) {
    this.selectedSites1 = selectedSites1;
}
private List<MpanVO> siteMpans;    
//private final static String[] hh_nhh_types;
private Map<String,String> hh_nhh_types;

private final static String[] adq_ren_types;
//private final static String[] cotOfferTypes;
private Map<String,String> cotOfferTypes;
private Map<String,String> offerType;

private Map<String,String> loadCurve;
//private final static String[] offerType;
//private final static String[] loadCurve;

private SelectItem[] hh_nhh_List;  
private SelectItem[] adq_ren_List;
private SelectItem[] cotOfferList;
private String cotOfferSelection;
private String comcOfferSelection;
private String copcOfferSelection;
private String offerTypeSelection;
private String loadCurveSelection;

//La oferta es de tipo HH o NHH
private String offerHH_NHH;

private SelectItem[] offerTypeList;
private SelectItem[] loadCurveList;

/**
 * Site selected.
 */
private SiteVO site;    
private MpanVO mpan;        
private List<SiteVO> sites;    
private List<MpanVO> mpans;

private List<TradebookVO> tradeBookList;
private Map<String,Integer> ProductList;    
private List<ProfileClassVO> profileClassList;        
private List<MddMeasurementClassVO> measurementClassList;
private Map<String,Integer> CurveList;

@PostConstruct    
public void init() {

    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("********************** CreateOffer::init **********************");
    }

    if (getMenuOrigin() == null) {
            setMenuOrigin(JSFHelper.getParameterFromView("OPTION"));     
            if (getMenuOrigin() == null) {
                setMenuOrigin((String) JSFHelper.getParameterFromRequest("OPTION"));
            }
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("CREATE OFFER --> guardado en VIEW VAR menuOrigin el "
                        + "valor recuperado en la Request del parametro OPTION:: " 
                        + getMenuOrigin());
            }
    }

    adq_ren_types[0] = "Adquisitions";
    adq_ren_types[1] = "Renews";

    //Valor por defecto de COT        
    cotOfferSelection="0";
    //Valor por defecto de COMC
    comcOfferSelection="0";
    //Valor por defecto de COPC
    copcOfferSelection="0";
    //Valor por defecto de OfferType
    offerTypeSelection="0";
    //Valor por defecto de loadCurve
    loadCurveSelection="0";

    offerHH_NHH="NHH";

    this.setHh_nhh_types(cargaHHNHH());

    //hh_nhh_List = createFilterOptions(hh_nhh_types);
    hh_nhh_List = createFilterOptions1(hh_nhh_types,true);
    adq_ren_List = createFilterOptions(adq_ren_types);        
    //cotOfferList = createFilterOptions(cotOfferTypes);
    this.setCotOfferTypes(cargaCOT());
    cotOfferList = createFilterOptions1(cotOfferTypes,false);
    this.setOfferType(cargaofferType());
    offerTypeList = createFilterOptions1(offerType,false);
    this.setLoadCurve(cargaloadCurve());
    loadCurveList = createFilterOptions1(loadCurve,false);

    populateRequestParamsInViewVars();

    initCustomerInfo();

    CurveList = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
    ProductList = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();

    //hh_nhh_List = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
    profileClassId=2;
    measurementClassId="A";
    curveId=1;
    tradeBookId=3;
    profileClassList = new ArrayList<ProfileClassVO>();        
    measurementClassList = new ArrayList<MddMeasurementClassVO>();
    tradeBookList = new ArrayList<TradebookVO>();

    loadProfileClass();
    loadMeasurementClass();
    loadTradeBook();        

    }
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  
    //FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Car Selected", ((Car) event.getObject()).getModel());    
    //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    //event.getComponent().
}  

public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {  
    //FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Car Unselected", ((Car) event.getObject()).getModel());    
    //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
}  

public String getOfferTypeSelection() {
    return offerTypeSelection;
}

public void setOfferTypeSelection(String offerTypeSelection) {
    this.offerTypeSelection = offerTypeSelection;
}

public String getLoadCurveSelection() {
    return loadCurveSelection;
}

public void setLoadCurveSelection(String loadCurveSelection) {
    this.loadCurveSelection = loadCurveSelection;
}

public SelectItem[] getOfferTypeList() {
    return offerTypeList;
}

public void setOfferTypeList(SelectItem[] offerTypeList) {
    this.offerTypeList = offerTypeList;
}

public SelectItem[] getLoadCurveList() {
    return loadCurveList;
}

public void setLoadCurveList(SelectItem[] loadCurveList) {
    this.loadCurveList = loadCurveList;
}

public List<ProfileClassVO> getProfileClassList() {
    return profileClassList;
}

public void setProfileClassList(List<ProfileClassVO> ProfileClassList) {
    this.profileClassList = ProfileClassList;
}  

public MpanVO getMpan() {
    return mpan;
}

public void setMpan(MpanVO mpan) {
    this.mpan = mpan;
}

public List<MpanVO> getMpans() {
    return mpans;
}

public void setMpans(List<MpanVO> mpans) {
    this.mpans = mpans;
}

public List<SiteVO> getSites() {
    return sites;
}

public void setSites(List<SiteVO> sites) {
    this.sites = sites;
}

public CustomerVO getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(CustomerVO customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public SiteVO getSite() {
    return site;
}

public void setSite(SiteVO site) {
    this.site = site;
}

public String getCreditScore() {
    return creditScore;
}

public void setCreditScore(String creditScore) {
    this.creditScore = creditScore;
}

public String getConsultantMargin() {
    return consultantMargin;
}

public void setConsultantMargin(String consultantMargin) {
    this.consultantMargin = consultantMargin;
}

public String getSpMargin() {
    return spMargin;
}

public void setSpMargin(String spMargin) {
    this.spMargin = spMargin;
}

public List<OfferSitesVO> getOfferSites() {
    return offerSites;
}

public void setOfferSites(List<OfferSitesVO> offerSites) {
    this.offerSites = offerSites;
}

public List<OfferSitesVO> getFilteredSites() {
    return filteredSites;
}

public void setFilteredSites(List<OfferSitesVO> filteredSites) {
    this.filteredSites = filteredSites;
}

public SelectItem[] getAdq_ren_List() {
    return adq_ren_List;
}

public void setAdq_ren_List(SelectItem[] adq_ren_List) {
    this.adq_ren_List = adq_ren_List;
}

public SelectItem[] getHh_nhh_List() {
    return hh_nhh_List;
}

public void setHh_nhh_List(SelectItem[] hh_nhh_List) {
    this.hh_nhh_List = hh_nhh_List;
}

public Map<String, String> getHh_nhh_types() {
    return hh_nhh_types;
}

public void setHh_nhh_types(Map<String, String> hh_nhh_types) {
    this.hh_nhh_types = hh_nhh_types;
}

public Map<String, String> getOfferType() {
    return offerType;
}

public void setOfferType(Map<String, String> offerType) {
    this.offerType = offerType;
}

public Map<String, String> getLoadCurve() {
    return loadCurve;
}

public void setLoadCurve(Map<String, String> loadCurve) {
    this.loadCurve = loadCurve;
}

public String getOfferHH_NHH() {
    return offerHH_NHH;
}

public void setOfferHH_NHH(String OfferHH_NHH) {
    this.offerHH_NHH = OfferHH_NHH;
}

public String getMenuOrigin() {
    return menuOrigin;
}

public void setMenuOrigin(String menuOrigin) {
    this.menuOrigin = menuOrigin;
}
/**
 * Metodo que inicializa los valores del cliente.
 */
private void initCustomerInfo() {        

    this.setSites(new ArrayList<SiteVO>());    
    this.setMpans(new ArrayList<MpanVO>());    
    List<OfferSitesVO> offerSitesAux = new ArrayList<OfferSitesVO>();

    FacesMessage msg = null;
    try{
        log.debug("initCustomerInfo: Start");

        IOffersBean offerBean = BeanInstanceLocator.getOffersBean();                
        this.setCustomer(offerBean.getCustomer(customerId));  
        this.setManagers(offerBean.getManagerList());


        if (CREATE_OFFERS_OPTION.equals(menuOrigin)){ 
            if (selectedSites!=null){
                for(int i = 0; i < selectedSites.length; i++){
                    offerSitesAux.add(selectedSites[i]);
                }
            }

            this.setOfferSites(offerSitesAux);
        }
        else{
            this.setOfferSites(offerBean.getCustomerSites(customerId));
        }                        


        this.setHh_nhh_List(offerBean.getHHNHHList());
        this.setAdq_ren_List(offerBean.getAdquisitionRenewList());


    }catch(Exception e){
        msg = new FacesMessage("ERROR "+e.getMessage());   
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);   
        log.error("ERROR 2:: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}        

public Integer getProductId() {
    return productId;
}

public void setProductId(Integer ProductId) {
    this.productId = ProductId;
}    

public List<TradebookVO> getTradeBookList() {
    return tradeBookList;
}

public void setTradebookList(List<TradebookVO> tradeBookList) {
    this.tradeBookList = tradeBookList;
}    

public List<MddMeasurementClassVO> getMeasurementClassList() {
    return measurementClassList;
}

public void setMeasurementClassList(List<MddMeasurementClassVO> MeasurementClassList) {
    this.measurementClassList = MeasurementClassList;
}   


public Integer getProfileClassId() {
    return profileClassId;
}

public void setProfileClassId(Integer ProfileClassId) {
    this.profileClassId = ProfileClassId;
}

public String getMeasurementClassId() {
    return measurementClassId;
}

public void setMeasurementClassId(String MeasurementClassId) {
    this.measurementClassId = MeasurementClassId;
}

public Integer getCurveId() {
    return curveId;
}

public void setCurveId(Integer CurveId) {
    this.curveId = CurveId;
}

public Integer getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

public Date getOfferFromDate() {
    return offerFromDate;
}

public void setOfferFromDate(Date OfferFromDate) {
    this.offerFromDate = OfferFromDate;
}

public Date getOfferToDate() {
    return offerToDate;
}

public void setOfferToDate(Date OfferToDate) {
    this.offerToDate = OfferToDate;
}

public Integer getTradeBookId() {
    return tradeBookId;
}

public void setTradeBookId(Integer tradeBookId) {
    this.tradeBookId = tradeBookId;
}

public Map<String, String> getManagers() {
    return managers;
}

public void setManagers(Map<String, String> managers) {
    this.managers = managers;
}

public OfferSitesVO getSelectedSite() {
    return selectedSite;
}

public void setSelectedSite(OfferSitesVO selectedSite) {
    this.selectedSite = selectedSite;
}

public OfferSitesVO[] getSelectedSites() {
    return selectedSites;
}    

public List<MpanVO> getSiteMpans() {
    return siteMpans;
}

public void setSiteMpans(List<MpanVO> siteMpans) {
    this.siteMpans = siteMpans;
}

public String getCopcOfferSelection() {
    return copcOfferSelection;
}

public void setCopcOfferSelection(String copcOfferSelection) {
    this.copcOfferSelection = copcOfferSelection;
}

public String getComcOfferSelection() {
    return comcOfferSelection;
}

public void setComcOfferSelection(String comcOfferSelection) {
    this.comcOfferSelection = comcOfferSelection;
}

public Map<String, String> getCotOfferTypes() {
    return cotOfferTypes;
}

public void setCotOfferTypes(Map<String, String> cotOfferTypes) {
    this.cotOfferTypes = cotOfferTypes;
}

public String getCotOfferSelection() {
    return cotOfferSelection;
}

public void setCotOfferSelection(String cotOfferSelection) {
    this.cotOfferSelection = cotOfferSelection;
}

public Date getExpiryDate() {
    return expiryDate;
}

public void setExpiryDate(Date expiryDate) {
    this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
}

public SelectItem[] getCotOfferList() {
    return cotOfferList;
}

public void setCotOfferList(SelectItem[] cotOfferList) {
    this.cotOfferList = cotOfferList;
}

private void loadProfileClass() {     

    FacesMessage msg = null;
    try{
        log.debug("ProfileClass: Start");

            IOffersBean offerBean = BeanInstanceLocator.getOffersBean();                
            List ProfileClassLista = offerBean.getProfileClassList(offerHH_NHH);                

            this.setProfileClassList((ArrayList<ProfileClassVO>) ProfileClassLista);                

            if(ProfileClassLista == null){
                msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"There are not Profile_class elements",null);
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);                     

        } 
        log.debug("ProfileClassLista: end");

    }catch(Exception e){
        msg = new FacesMessage("ERROR "+e.getMessage());   
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);   
        log.error("ERROR 2:: "+e.getMessage());
    }   
}


private void loadMeasurementClass() {     

    FacesMessage msg;
    try{
        log.debug("MeasurementClass: Start");

            IOffersBean offerBean = BeanInstanceLocator.getOffersBean();
            List MeasureClassList = offerBean.getMeasurementClassList();                      

            this.setMeasurementClassList((ArrayList<MddMeasurementClassVO>) MeasureClassList);

            if(measurementClassList == null){
                msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"There are not Measurement_class elements",null);
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
        }
        log.debug("loadMeasurementClass: end");            

    }catch(Exception e){
        msg = new FacesMessage("ERROR "+e.getMessage());   
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);   
        log.error("ERROR 2:: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I can only see the value of properties updated in @PostContruct of the first bean

Comment: Please clarify your question. What are you trying to achieve? Pass a value from one ViewScoped bean to another ViewScoped bean?

Comment: Preferably post the code of the two beans to see how you do it.

Comment: Any ideas that could be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

> I have injected one request scoped bean into another view scoped bean

You're not allowed to inject a bean into another bean of a wider scope.

As a rule, the following abominations are not allowed :)

1. `@RequestScoped` >> `@ViewScoped`
2. `@ViewScoped` >>`@SessionScoped`
3. `@SessionScoped` >> `@ApplicationScoped`

EDIT (Based on your update): Injecting a property of a bean, as against injecting the bean itself, will result in a static injection. The static injection means that the value that's injected into the target is what's available as at the time of injection. As a the time the following line was executed:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{selectOfferMpans.selectedSites}")
```

`selectedSites` is null. So what you should be doing there instead is injecting the entire bean

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{selectOfferMpans}")
```

This way, you'll have access to the current value of whatever variable you're interested in

Comment: sorry that was a typo, both are @ViewScoped

Comment: If I inject the bean itself, when I ask for the value of `selectedSites` the result is also null, only on properties updated in `@PostContruct` of the first bean I can access their true value

Comment: @user2366464 - Well it simply means those values are null. Maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly. If the bean has not been previously referenced within the same page, the first time you request for it is the first time it'll be instantiated. Naturally, its member variables will all be initialized to null. Now, in the `@PostConstructor` the values have been set, so they'll be available. None of this behaviour is unexpected IMO

Comment: @user2366464 - So where exactly in the code you've posted here are you calling `findCustomer`?

Comment: Bean 1: property selectedSites It's loaded in `findCustomer` Method, so it's not null.                                                                                             Bean 2: I inject the bean 1. If I ask for the getter of `selectedSites`, the value appears as null(and it's not). On the other hand, I can see the correct value of property `hh_nhh_List` of the injected bean. The behaviour is different in those properties of the same injected bean

Comment: I call `findCustomer` from this xhtml  `<p:commandButton id="pCBFind" styleClass="centerAbs" type="submit" icon="ui-icon-search" value="#{text['selectOfferMpans.find']}"
                                             actionListener="#{selectOfferMpans.findCustomer}"`

Comment: Then other commandButton action navigates to the page using bean 2

Comment: @user2366464 - Your question is beginning to look like it lacks a bunch of context. I'm sorry, I don't think I can help here

Comment: Wlll let's simplify the issue. If I inject one backing bean into another bean, both Viewscoped, why some properties can return their value and others return null(and are not null)? All of them have their getters and setters